# Git SSH "permission denied" in macOS 13 Ventura

Tags: macos, ssh, git, public-key, macos-ventura

When I try to authenticate with an RSA SSH key in macOS 13 (Ventura), I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.
However, when I use the same command against macOS 12 (Monterrey), it works correctly.

Comment: try ```ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss user@old_server```

Comment: @hanshenrik Can you explain a little where to use this piece of code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

macOS 13 (Ventura) ships with OpenSSH_9.0p1. According to the OpenSSH release notes:

> This release disables RSA signatures using the SHA-1 hash algorithm
> by default. This change has been made as the SHA-1 hash algorithm is
> cryptographically broken, and it is possible to create chosen-prefix
> hash collisions for <USD$50K [1]

A workaround is described in this Reddit thread: [SSH in Ventura](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/v8jt42/ssh_in_ventura/)

Perhaps a better solution is to generate keys based on a more secure hash algorithm. For the time being, I'm switching to ed25519, which can be generated like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "comment"
```

Comment: The best solution would be to upgrade the server's SSH software if possible. Although originally SSHv2 only defined RSA to be used in combination with SHA-1, the RSA keys themselves aren't _inherently_ tied to any specific hash algorithm and will automatically be used with SHA2-256 when both client and server support the new combination (although switching to ed25519 keys is still a good idea).

Answer (score 31):

You need to generate a new set of keys based on a more secure hash algorithm. It is [generally](https://goteleport.com/blog/comparing-ssh-keys/) [recommended](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to use `ed25519` algorithm.

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C hello@example.com
ssh-add -A
```

---

In case you absolutely can't upgrade SSH (support added in OpenSSH 6.4) and you have to use RSA/SHA1 (e.g. the server accepts only RSA/SHA1 and you can't change that), add this snippet to the top of `~/.ssh/config` on the client side (create the folder and file if it doesn't exist).

```
Host your-old-host.example.com
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

It enables RSA/SHA1 both in host key and public key, should solve both this problem and related "no matching host key type found" problem.

Comment: This is usually the correct answer, but it doesn't exactly "enable RSA" – it enables RSA/SHA1, for outdated servers that do not support RSA/SHA256. Modern OpenSSH servers support RSA/SHA256 (and the exact same id_rsa keys can be used with both algorithms); unfortunately, if the server accepts only RSA (e.g. appliances) it's almost guaranteed to be old enough to require RSA/SHA1 specifically.

Comment: This worked for me (OSX Ventura ssh to an old Ubuntu 14 box) and for clarity - I added this on the client side, and created a new file called config which didn't exist before.  I didn't set any special permissions on the file.

Comment: Please dont add this to `Host *`! This is terrible practice. The real solution is to upgrade the remote server to a version greater than OpenSSH 7.2. If that doesn't work, add it per host IP or in the command line command when connecting.
I.E. - `ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa {user@host}`

Comment: @Tony-Caffe I've submitted an edit to remove that dangerous advice.

Comment: What is dangerous about adding a new pubkey algo to Host *? Please explain as it's only enabling the use of your ssh key on older versions.

Additionally HostkeyAlgorithms is not needed at all here for the question posted and is just addressing a random issue this person had.

Comment: You can localize the config on a per server basis if you don't to make it a global change, by adding below snippet to your ~/.ssh/config file instead of /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

Host myserver.com
  Hostname ssh.myserver.com
  Port 443
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa

Answer (score 7):

This solution works for me.

0. (Backup ~/.ssh/ folder)
1. If your ssh config and private/public keys are in /etc/ssh/ before upgrading the MacOS

- copy ssh_config to ~/.ssh/config
- copy all private/public keys to ~/.ssh/

2. Adding the following lines at the end of ~/.ssh/config

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Answer (score 2):

Please dont add this to `Host *`! This is terrible practice. The real solution is to upgrade the remote server to a version greater than OpenSSH 7.2. If that doesn't work, add it per host IP or in the command line command when connecting.

I.E. - `ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa {user@host}`

You can check your client keys and see if they support SHA256 and if they do, then no new keys are needed at the moment. If it doesnt say SHA256, then toss those keys and get something stronger using `ssh-keygen` command.

`ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

from https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/1003

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers are just blindly throwing up new config options that aren't needed.

To solve this issue you can run the following command.

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
3072 SHA256:/redacted /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (RSA)
```

Then you can take a look at the supported public keys for your ssh config.

```
$ ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

In most cases adding ssh-rsa will work or you can limit it to rsa-sha2-256 as well using the following. The other config people are posting is not needed in almost any case just the following line.

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

In the case that you are using ssh certs however you will want to run the following command on your cert.

```
$ ssh-keygen -L -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub
/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub:
        Type: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate
        Public key: RSA-CERT SHA256:/redacted
        Signing CA: RSA SHA256:redacted (using rsa-sha2-256)
        Key ID: "something"
        Serial: 123
        Valid: from 2023-04-04T13:19:10 to 2023-04-05T09:19:40
```

In this case you will need do add the Type field to the PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms like so.

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Comment: See [the other answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1751591/354504) on the dangers of adding `Host *`

Comment: @Randall I'm sorry but that answer says nothing about the danger of adding Host * it just says "Hey I think this is dangerous. Trust me!". That is just cargo culting an answer around without an explanation. Sure it's better to specify things but like everything in tech the answer is it depends. In my most peoples case it won't matter and I am really struggling to see how it's dangerous and not just bad practice.

Please enlighten me of the actual danger of this. I already know why it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

#### For PIV authentication

Granted, this deviates from the OP's issue with RSA keys.
I got the following error using ssh/PIV authentication after upgrading to Ventura:

```
Infinite reexec detected; aborting
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe
```

The fix was:

1. Remove or comment out the `PKCS11Provider` line in your `~/.ssh/config`
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   ssh-add -e /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib
     #Note - above command may produce the error:  
     #   'Could not remove card "/usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib": agent refused operation'
     #This can be ignored; the file simply has no items to remove
   ssh-add -D
   killall -9 ssh-agent
   ssh-add -s /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib
   ```
3. You should now be able to ssh

<sub>*Note*: *If ssh still fails* - The `killall` should have cleared all cached ssh process/keys/etc.  A reboot will definitely clear any cached data that may be interfering.</sub>