# Can not connect with SFTP Sublime to OS X server

Tags: sftp, sublime-text-3, packages

I have an SFTP server running on OS X that I want to connect to with the SFTP package in Sublime Text using macOS and connected with FileZilla without any issue.

For some reason, I get a timeout every time I try to connect to it. I have copied the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from server into my local machine `~/.ssh/dem.pub` directory and use it my `sftp_config.json` as below.

```
// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "myhost.com",
"user": "root",
// "password": "password",
"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/path",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 100,
"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/dev.pub",
```

Still getting timeout and really got stuck with this.

I have checked this but in this case used Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817766/cant-connect-to-sftp-server-through-sublime-3-package-sftp

Comment: Check this [question and answer thread out](https://superuser.com/a/1749370/167207). This might be a case of you running macOS 13 (Ventura) and the OS X server you are connecting to using RSA/SHA1 host keys. Host kets are not the SSH public key stuff but rather the host identification keys that ID the host to a client.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks it helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git SSH "permission denied" in macOS 13 Ventura](https://superuser.com/questions/1749364/git-ssh-permission-denied-in-macos-13-ventura)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes and thank you