# SSH isn't using “~/.ssh/config” in macOS 13.1 (Ventura)

Tags: macos, ssh, git, github, ssh-agent

After quite a long time between reboots, I did one.

After rebooting I was working on some code hosted on GitHub, however

```
> ssh -T MY_USERNAME@github.com
MY_USERNAME@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Now, I have previously followed the steps in [Generate new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to generate the SSH key.

However, after rebooting it seems like neither the `ssh-agent` is started (not present in any startup scripts) nor that the identities are added after starting the `ssh-agent`.

I'm kind of at a loss of where to start troubleshooting, as I cannot see why `ssh` doesn't make use of the config in `~/.ssh/config` that I have set up.

Note: Booting up the `ssh-agent` with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and adding them using `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain <path to private key>` seems to work fine.
This also works when added to my `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, but if I am not mistaken, this should not be necessary when the `~/.ssh/config` is set up.

Any help would be much appreciated

***Edit 1:***
The following is my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *.github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rk_gmail

# Fig ssh integration. Keep at the bottom of this file.
Match all
  Include ~/.fig/ssh
```

Comment: This might not be a credentials issue but an SSH protocol issue. It might be a host key issue because the destination server is out of date and only uses older/insecure protocols. This is a known issue and the answer [can be found here](https://superuser.com/a/1749370/167207).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git SSH "permission denied" in macOS 13 Ventura](https://superuser.com/questions/1749364/git-ssh-permission-denied-in-macos-13-ventura)

Comment: Thanks for your responses

I've also added the `~/.ssh/config` as an edit to the post @KamilMaciorowski

@Giacomo1968, I have taken a look at that post previously yes. As per the GitHub docs I used ed25519 as the encryption algorithm.

Comment: After following the github guide for [generating a new SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) everything seems to work. That makes it likely that there was a user error on my end.

For the next person who comes here, please try following the documentation as written without deviation and see if this solves your problem.